# Dynamically change size of dialog box - MFC

Tags: mfc, dialog

I am using a "Dialog" in my MFC project. I populate this dialog dynamically with edit controls and static text controls.
I want this dialog to change the size dynamically based on the number of controls.

Eg: If I have 2 edit controls, the length of the dialog will be comparatively smaller than than with 5 edit controls.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138040/how-to-create-a-resizable-cdialog-in-mfc

Comment: Thanks. I think I was looking for "MoveWindow". I found an example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632598(v=VS.85).aspx#creating_enumerating_etc
Thanks again.