# MFC equivalent of Qt QVBoxLayout widget

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I'd like to know how to position MFC controls in the dialog so that they stretch to fill free space in the dialog. In Qt it is possible to nest QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout widgets, I'm looking for something similar in MFC.

Additionally I'd be interested to know if there exists an MFC control similar to the Qt QTableWidget that can have other widgets nested in each cell.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/5739620/5987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no layout managers in MFC. A big lack indeed...

Answer (score 1):

Not difficult to find on the web..
Resizable layouts:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WndResizer.aspx

Not sure on the grid control with widgets in it, maybe this will do it with some modifications:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to use only the functionality provided in the MFC library.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote on this? yes MFC itself does not contain this functionality, but both of those articles point to a solution of the original question by extending MFC.