# Handling OnSize function or resizable dialog in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2005

In one MFC application there is a paned window. 
On that window,

I have added a menu-bar and a toolbar and lots of other controls. 
The paned window is re-sizable.

Now for the re-sizable window, I have override the function OnSize(). There I have retrieved the top window size and then below it and so on...
Then for every control I have retrieved it's window and called MoveWindow().

I just wants to be assured is it the correct way for handling resizable window/ dialog in MFC or there is some other ways available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel: try the [ResizableLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1175/ResizableLib).
It can handle resizing of dialogs in a very easy way and you don't have to worry about every detail yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When moving a large number of controls at once, it is preferable to use [`DeferWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681(v=vs.85).aspx) to minimize the repainting. I have an example of how to use it for a resizable MFC dialog at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5739620/5987.