# How resize a with and height both are evenly

Tags: c++, mfc, resize, customdialog

> I would like to give resize option for my custom dialog. I done this
>   but i need to handle if he resize a width of that dialog at a same time need to resize
>   height also. like WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT move.
>
> I don't know how to done this please help me?
>
> Advance Thanks  bala

Comment: Start with [my resizable dialog class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138040/how-to-create-a-resizable-cdialog-in-mfc) and modify the `OnGetMinMaxInfo` function.

Comment: I can't understand can you explain me ?

Comment: The OnGetMinMaxInfo function determines the size that the dialog is allowed to have. Just take the difference between the new and original width and height, take whichever is larger, and use it to adjust the coordinates that are returned.

Comment: sorry can you give some code explanation ?

Comment: @user The link Mark posted in his first comment contains fully functional code.