# How do I make my C++ windows application resize friendly?

Tags: c++, windows, resize

I am writing trying to learn some C++, so I'm creating a simple Windows application. I was wondering, how can do I make items - such as textboxes, automatically move and resize according to the size of window. I know that in Visual Basic they use anchors, but how do I do it in C++? Has anybody got any examples I could borrow? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5739620/5987

Comment: It's **not about language but about library** (or no library) you're using to design your user interface. Plain Win32 API? Win32 + MFC? WTL? WT? OWL? QT? wxWidgets? Another one?

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to use a library... Which would you recommend?

Comment: To ask for a library isn't a good question for SO (because everyone has his own preferences so it's just about opinion and pretty broad). It depends on your programming background and your compiler/IDE (mainly, IMO).

Comment: I am using Dev-C++ and I have lots of experience with mark-up languages - from website production and games development - and I know my way around C-based languages - from games development and some software development.

Comment: @Xanco: He means that you _are_ using a library already to do GUI. You _must_ be. C++ itself doesn't have GUI features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you are using Visual Studio.

FILE -> New -> Project

Select "MFC Application" and enter a name below.

You now get the "MFC Application Wizard".

Select "Application Type" from the list on the left.

Select "Dialog based".

Select Finish.

You now get a dialog that you can populate just like VB but it has created all the basic C++ code behind it so you can get experimenting.

To resize the controls with the dialog you must intercept the sizing message with a OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) call, use the class wizard to do this.

Good luck.

Comment: Looks like he's using Dev-Cpp. And there is no hint that he's using MFC. But nice try. ;)