# Cannot load image in picture control MFC with resizeable form

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, mfc

I have interesting question about load image in picture control of MFC. I have a form that can resize. I do it using the method of [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138040/how-to-create-a-resizable-cdialog-in-mfc). I write that method in `CResizableDialog.cpp`. To used it, in my class I used

```
class CFace_Recognition_MFCDlg : public CResizableDialog
```

And my form have a picture control form with `IDC_IMG` is

```
CStatic pic1;
void CFace_Recognition_MFCDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CResizableDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IMG, pic1);
}
```

Finally, I using opencv to read image and convert it to bmp. Then display it into picture control by code

```
IplImage *img;
IplImage *resize;

img=cvLoadImage("phongcanh.jpg",CV_INTER_LINEAR);
if(img==0){
    exit(0);
}
resize = cvCreateImage(cvSize(400,300),img->depth, img->nChannels); 
cvResize(img, resize, 1);           
pic1.SetBitmap(IplImage2DIB(resize));  
cvReleaseImage(&img);
```

The function IplImage2DIB works well. But I cannot show the image into the picture control. I check and I find that the problem in the function

```
CResizableDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IMG, pic1);
```

But I don't know how to edit it. Because I am working with a [resizeable form](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/how-to-create-resizable-dialogs-in-mfc/). Could you help me to fix it? Thanks

Comment: please use cv::Mat, not IplImages. opencv's legacy c-api is a dead end.

Comment: pic1 must be a member variable of the dialog class.  If you are getting an error message or an assertion please tell us what it is.

Comment: If I used CFace_Recognition_MFCDlg::DoDataExchange(pDX);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_IMG, pic1); and run it crashes with Unhandled exception at 0x01059A29 in Face_Recognition_MFC.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x010D2FEC).

Answer (score 0):

`CResizableDialog` is a limited framework for resizable Layout. My guess: it simply doesn't cover resizing of an image in a `CStatic` after dialog creation. Just have a look at the ResizableLib source code.

If this is the case, make the `CStatic` invisible (while still maintaining the resizable anchor) and use its position in `OnDraw()` or `OnEraseBkgnd()` to draw the image yourself.