# How to move a control while resizing dialog size in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I've made a view on dialog in MFC.

You can see well from the following image.(like slider control and edit box, etc)

These controls are not moved when I resize a dialog size.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxAK.jpg)

I'd like to move the controls to fit dialog. but not need to resize of controls.

What should I do for solving for this problem?

## update 1

Especially, I want to set the slider position.

So firstly, I add member variable of slider 'CSliderCtrl sss'  to dialog class then  I made this in OnSize();

```
 OnSize()
{
....
sss.MoveWindow(10, 10,cx-20,cy-60);
....

}
```

BTW,  the problem is that the first position of slider difference between after resize of dialog.

So I want to know that how to set first position of slider in InitialDialog.

## update 2

I've got followed up with your source. but it's difference working between you and me.

When I run first I got this 
[image]

When I resize the dialog a very little I got this
[image]

As you can see, the slider is disappeared.

I have update here the MyDlg.cpp

```
// mfc_test5Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mfc_test5.h"
#include "mfc_test5Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "Testview.h"
#include <Magick++.h>
extern CTestview *global_TestView;
char * fileposition;


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

    // Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    // Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Cmfc_test5Dlg dialog




Cmfc_test5Dlg::Cmfc_test5Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Cmfc_test5Dlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_CString(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    fileposition = (char*)this;
    m_pTestView = NULL;
}

void Cmfc_test5Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SLIDER1, m_CSliderCtrl);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_CString);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Cmfc_test5Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE, IDC_SLIDER1, &Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnNMReleasedcaptureSlider1)
    ON_WM_DROPFILES()
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



BOOL Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
     GetClientRect(&m_SaveRect);

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.


    CRuntimeClass *pObject;
    pObject = RUNTIME_CLASS(CTestview);
    m_pTestView = (CTestview*)pObject->CreateObject();
    CRect crt;
    GetClientRect(&crt);
    int x,y;
     x = crt.Width();
     y  = crt.Height();
     //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653087/how-to-move-a-control-while-resizing-dialog-size-in-mfc
//   m_CSliderCtrl.SetWindowPos(0,x-293,y-125,x-293,y-125,SWP_NOSIZE /*SWP_NOZORDER*/);

    if (!m_pTestView->Create(NULL, NULL, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW, CRect(0, 0,x-200 ,y), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create view window\n");
        return -1;
    }


    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    m_CSliderCtrl.SetRange(0,255); //Reference Here (http://system.tistory.com/13)
    m_CSliderCtrl.SetRangeMin(0);
    m_CSliderCtrl.SetRangeMax(255);
    m_CSliderCtrl.SetPos(128);
    m_CSliderCtrl.SetLineSize(1);
    m_CString.Format(_T("%d"), 0); //Reference here (http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/tutorial_3.html)


    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}



void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnNMReleasedcaptureSlider1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    int value = m_CSliderCtrl.GetPos(); //Reference Here (http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/tutorial_3.html)
    m_CString.Format(_T("%d"), value);
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    *pResult = 0;
}


void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{

    int nFiles;
    static char szPathName[MAX_PATH]; // 파일 경로면이 들어간다.
    CString strFileName;

    ::DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0, szPathName, MAX_PATH);

    ::DragFinish(hDropInfo);
    CDialog::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);
    CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);

    fileposition = szPathName;
    if (m_pTestView != NULL)
        m_pTestView->DoDisplayImage();


}


int Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // TODO:  Add your specialized creation code here


    return 0;
}

void OffsetChildWindow(CWnd* child, int dx, int dy, int dw, int dh)
{
    if (!child)
    {
        return; //Add error handling, control does not exits
    }

    if (!child->GetParent()) 
    {
        return;
    }

    //find child window's coordinates relative to top-left of parent
    CRect rc;
    child->GetClientRect(&rc);
    CPoint p(0, 0);
    ScreenToClient(child->GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), &p);
    rc.OffsetRect(p);

    //prevent negative size
    if ((rc.Width() + dw) < 0) dw = -rc.Width();
    if ((rc.Height() + dh) < 0) dh = -rc.Height();

   child->SetWindowPos(0, rc.left + dx, rc.top + dy, rc.Width() + dw, rc.Height() + dh, SWP_NOZORDER);


    child->Invalidate(FALSE);
}

void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialogEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    if (!cx || !cy)
        return;


    if (m_pTestView)
    {
        m_pTestView->MoveWindow(0, 0, cx-200, cy);
    }


    int dx = cx - m_SaveRect.right;
    int dy = cy - m_SaveRect.bottom;

    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_SLIDER1), 0,dy,dx,0);
    GetClientRect(&m_SaveRect);

}
```

and here is header file.

```
// mfc_test5Dlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "Testview.h"
#include "atltypes.h"



// Cmfc_test5Dlg dialog
class Cmfc_test5Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    Cmfc_test5Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);    // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFC_TEST5_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CSliderCtrl m_CSliderCtrl;
private:
    CString m_CString;
public:
    afx_msg void OnNMReleasedcaptureSlider1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
    afx_msg void OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo);
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    CTestview *m_pTestView;
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
    CRect m_SaveRect;
};
```

## update 3

I have updated. but it does not stll work well.
When I resize the dialog to left a little.
[image]

when I resize the dialog to left so many.
[image]

When I resize the dialog to right.
[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138040/how-to-create-a-resizable-cdialog-in-mfc

Comment: I didn't understand your second edit. Maybe you want to move the control up/down, while increasing/decreasing the width during resize?

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani : Yes, exactly you are right.  I want move the control during resize. Because the contols are disappeard while resizie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method, use this function:

```
void OffsetChildWindow(CWnd* child, int dx, int dy, int dw, int dh)
{
    if (!child) return;
    if (!child->GetParent()) return;
    if (!IsWindow(child->m_hWnd)) return;

    //find child window's coordinates relative to top-left of parent
    CRect rc;
    child->GetWindowRect(&rc);
    CPoint p(0, 0);
    ScreenToClient(child->GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), &p);
    rc.OffsetRect(p);

    //prevent negative size
    if ((rc.Width() + dw) < 0) dw = -rc.Width();
    if ((rc.Height() + dh) < 0) dh = -rc.Height();

    child->SetWindowPos(0, rc.left + dx, rc.top + dy, rc.Width() + dw, rc.Height() + dh, SWP_NOZORDER);
    child->Invalidate(FALSE);
}
```

Declare a member variable as follows: `CRect m_SaveRect;`

```
//Initialize
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    GetClientRect(&m_SaveRect);
    ...
}

void CMyDialog::OnSize(UINT f, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialogEx::OnSize(f, cx, cy);

    if (!cx || !cy)
        return;

    //(this error check is needed on at least one child control)
    if (!GetDlgItem(IDOK)) return; //not ready yet

    int dx = cx - m_SaveRect.right;
    int dy = cy - m_SaveRect.bottom;

    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL), dx, dy, 0, 0);
    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDOK), dx, dy, 0, 0);
    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_SLIDER1), 0, dy, dx, 0);
    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1), 0, 0, dx, dy);

    GetClientRect(&m_SaveRect);
}
```

`dx` or `dy` can be zero if you need only one of horizontal/vertical offset.

While we are at it, you may also need to add `ON_WM_GETMINMAXINFO` to message map to prevent the dialog from becoming too small:

```
void CMyDialog::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO *mx)
{
    mx->ptMinTrackSize.x = 400; //minimum 400x300 size
    mx->ptMinTrackSize.y = 300;
    CDialogEx::OnGetMinMaxInfo(mx);
}
```

[image]
[image]

### -------------------------------------------------------

<s>Edit 2</s>

**Edit 3**

Copy/Paste these 2 functions `OffsetChildWindow` and `Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnSize` and remove the old functions. I have made updates.

```
void OffsetChildWindow(CWnd* child, int dx, int dy, int dw, int dh)
{
    if (!child) return;
    if (!child->GetParent()) return;
    if (!IsWindow(child->m_hWnd)) return;

    //find child window's coordinates relative to top-left of parent
    CRect rc;
    child->GetWindowRect(&rc);
    CPoint p(0, 0);
    ScreenToClient(child->GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), &p);
    rc.OffsetRect(p);

    //prevent negative size
    if ((rc.Width() + dw) < 0) dw = -rc.Width();
    if ((rc.Height() + dh) < 0) dh = -rc.Height();

    child->SetWindowPos(0, rc.left + dx, rc.top + dy, rc.Width() + dw, rc.Height() + dh, SWP_NOZORDER);
    child->Invalidate(FALSE);
}

void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDialogEx::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    if (!cx || !cy) return;

    int dx = cx - m_SaveRect.right;
    int dy = cy - m_SaveRect.bottom;

    OffsetChildWindow(m_pTestView, 0,0,dx,dy);
    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_SLIDER1), dx,dy,0,0);
    OffsetChildWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1), dx,dy,0,0);
    GetClientRect(&m_SaveRect);
}
```

Comment: Thanks But I've got a error message as following when I build at this " CPoint p = { 0 };" "mfc_test5Dlg.cpp(260): error C2552: 'p' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
          'CPoint' : Types with a base are not aggregate"

Comment: Also I have got a error message "Unhandled exception at 0x00361fbe in mfc_test5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020." when I across run at here "  if (!child->GetParent()) return;" I think there's some problems.

Comment: No, I'm still work with your source code. I've got something wrong. it's difference work between you and me.

Comment: Show the complete "mydialog.cpp" and "mydialog.h" files. You can edit your question and copy/paste. Then make a comment here so I get notified that you have made changes to the question.

Comment: I have update  "mydialog.cpp" and "mydialog.h" files

Comment: I also added more error handling for `OffsetChildWindow`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my dialog status. it does not work well.

Comment: See **Edit 3** It should work if you copy/paste those 2 functions. Do exact copy/paste, remove the old functions.

Comment: ps, I had another error when copying, it should be `OffsetChildWindow(m_pTestView, 0,0,dx,dy);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

[CResizableDialog in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568/CResizableDialog)