# Scale all control to window size

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a dialog based application which contain controls such treectrl,listsctrl and group box contain all the buttons control. I am working in Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition.All controls are placed in the Dialog at design time and no control is created at run time.

Using

```
int desktopW = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN); 
int desktopH = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
```

got the width and height of window, then found the relative position of the controls.

Using `SetWindowPos` try to change the width and height of various control, if new width and height is less than old control width and height.

But that involves a lot of calculation.

Is there exist any easy way to change the control position/scaling based on window size?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/138040/5987 helps.

Comment: I used to use this before the new IDE resizing features: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11538/Resize-Reposition-the-Controls-in-a-Dialog-at-your

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dynamic Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout?view=vs-2019) for the controls.

See the Properties of each control. Then by using the *Moving Type* and *Sizing Type* properties you can specify how the control must move and/or resize as the dialog frame resizes.

[image: dynamic-layout-properties]

Comment: I am working in VS 2010 Professional Edition and can't see the above settings.

Comment: This is only available from VS2015 on.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes correct, but that info was only added to the question after my answer. Leaving it here for posterity.